# Informatica conditional

Tags: informatica

I am trying to add some logic to my expression table (`exp_source`). Basically, if the field `o_field_digital__c` is 'Yes' then change it to 'Y'. If its 'No' then change it to 'N' and if it's Null then just leave it blank. I put in the following and its showing syntax error

```
IIF(o_Field_DRC_Choice_Eligible__c = 'Yes', 'Y')
IIF(o_Field_DRC_Choice_Eligible__c = 'No', 'N')
```

Can you please fix this? Do I only need one IIF statement? this obviously has syntax errors

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand it is a transformation not a table.

Second, you can't change the value of an input port - you can only create a new calculated variable or output port

Last... IIF syntax is
    IIF(condition, return true, return false)

As you can see you haven't provided a value for the return false argument which ironically is where you should have nested the subsequent IIF. Also you will have to specify to otherwise leave blank in the missing return part of the nested IIF.

to correct you will need to nest  them so

```
IIF(o_Field_DRC_Choice_Eligible__c = 'Yes', 'Y', IIF(o_Field_DRC_Choice_Eligible__c = 'No', 'N', ''))
```

Comment: I'd just add one thing: make sure the o_Field_DRC_Choice_Eligible__c is not an output-only port (as the name seems to suggest), as you cannot create expressions based on ouput-only ports.

Comment: True. Didn't even notice the portname when I copied it verbatim

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below logic for the purpose, if none of the condition is matched it will default the output to blank:

```
DECODE(true,
o_Field_DRC_Choice_Eligible__c = 'Yes','Y',
o_Field_DRC_Choice_Eligible__c = 'No', 'N',
ISNULL(o_Field_DRC_Choice_Eligible__c),'',
'')
```